# Инициализация двумерного динамического массива

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, инициализация

Я пытаюсь инициализировать все элементы двумерного массива при его объявлении:

```cpp
int** ints = new int* [n] { new int[n] { 0 } };
```

При попытку вывести элементы

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << "i = " << i << "; j = " << j << "; value = " << ints[i][j] << endl;
```

я получаю такой результат в консоли:

```
i = 0; j = 0; value = 0
i = 0; j = 1; value = 0
i = 0; j = 2; value = 0
i = 1; j = 0; value =
```

Вызывается исключение: `нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x0000000000000000`.

Не могу понять, что происходит.

`n = 3`.

---

При выведении элементов одномерного массива, инициализированного таким образом:

```cpp
int* ints = new int[5];
```

в консоль выведется

```
-842150451
-842150451
-842150451
-842150451
-842150451
```

, а таким:

```cpp
int* ints = new int[5] { 0 };
```

-

```
0
0
0
0
0
```

.

Comment: `new int[n] { 0 }` инициализирует только первый элемент указателем на выделенную память

Comment: Вы ухитрились всем элементам, кроме первого, присвоить нулевой указатель...

Comment: @VTT а почему? Что происходит во вторым? Почему даже значение элемента второго элемента нельзя получить?

Comment: Видимо вы рассчитывали на то, что `new int[n] { 0 }` будет вызываться для каждого элемента, однако все, кроме первого, будут инициализироваться нулями.

Comment: @VTT массивами то они должны, по идее, остаться, даже если они инициализированы нулями. Или в двумерном массиве ссылки (ну или указатели) на одномерные хранятся?

Comment: Да, у вас в массиве хранятся указатели на массивы. Вы же сами написали `new int* [n]` - "массив из n указателей на int"...

Comment: Если хотите красивее, возьмите `std::vector`. Будет что-то типа `std::vector<std::vector<int>> ints(n, std::vector<int>(n));`, без цикла. К тому же это безопаснее: нельзя забыть освободить память, или сделать это неправильно.

Comment: "сделать, как в питоне" - `::std::vector ints{n, ::std::vector{n, 0, ::std::allocator<int>{}}};` А еще лучше - сделать один массив `n x n` а потом индексировать элементы. Это также позволит производить итерацию по элементам с использованием одного итератора.

Comment: Я сейчас подумал: возможно, в питоне для массива сначала выделяется память, а потом только он заполняется значениями, просто это скрыто под маской лаконичности. `vector` же, наверное, в своей внутренней логике тоже должен сначала выделять под массив память, а потом только его заполнять?

Comment: *"vector же, наверное, в своей внутренней логике тоже должен сначала выделять под массив память, а потом только его заполнять"* Да.

Comment: Ожидать, что инициализатор `{ }` "размножит" значение в массиве - это я еще могу понять, хоть это и не так. Но ожидать, что инициализатор `{ }` еще и размножит вычисления вложенного выражения `new int[n] { 0 }`, то есть корректно выделит память для каждой строки матрицы отдельно - это уже довольно высокий и далекий полет воображения. Совершенно необоснованный.

Comment: @AnT ну а вдруг? В питоне же можно примерно так сделать.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Почему если в питоне что-то можно, то и в крестах такое должно быть? Питон как-то связан с крестами?  В питоне есть типы или указатели? Совершенно разные языки же.

Comment: @vegorov почему, если что-то есть в одном языке, этого не может быть в другом? Вам что-то не нравится?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия Почему не может? Может. Но не обязано. И ожидать того, что нечто из одного языка обязательно будет в другом несколько... Ну не знаю... Наивно, что-ли....

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов господи, я перепутал, что происходит с массивом, если написать после его инициализации одно значение в фигурных скобках, потом попробовал сделать так с двумерным массивом!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При инициализации массива с указанным размером отсутствующие инициализаторы - нули. Т.е.

```
int a[5] = {6};
```

заполняет массив `a` значениями 6,0,0,0,0.

Заметим - инициализация значением, а не вычислением выражения :)

```
int i = 0;
int a[5] = {i++};
```

не будет применять `i++` ко всем элементам массива.

Что же делает

```
new int* [n] { new int[n] { 0 } };
```

? Вычисляется *единственное* значение `new int[n] { 0 }`, присваивается первому элементу массива. Остальные заполняются нулями. Дальнейшее понятно? :)

Если вы хотите использовать **именно C++**, а не некий мутированный C, то `vector` вам в руки:

```
vector<vector<int>> ints(n, vector<int>(n,0));
```

И никаких забот с освобождением памяти :)

**Update**

По дополненному вопросу - при полном отсутствии инициализатора как такового никакая инициализация не выполняется, и массив в результате заполнен мусором.

Comment: Мне показалось, что `int a[5] = {6}` заполнит все элементы массива шестёрками.

Comment: Ни в коем случае... Но даже если бы это было так - то у вас все элементы массива были бы заполнены одним и тем же указателем! Что точно так же плохо...

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А я - ответ....